# Terra Term Macro Baud Rate Adjustment

Tags: macros, baud-rate, teraterm

I'm trying to make a macro for adjusting the baud rate of radios but I've run into some trouble and I haven't been able to find a solution through google search. I'm using the application terra term.

**'Link macro first. Use 'connect macro'** is the first error that is given when I try to run the macro. Here is the macro.

```
connect ttpmacro
initBaudRate=115200 ;
endBaudRate=9600 ;
setbaud initBaudRate
send 'at+ipr=' endBautRate
setbaud endBaudRate
send 'at&w'
setbaud initBaudRate
```

Of course there are a few other errors after this regarding syntax but I'm most interested in fixing the first error first, its my first time using ttl so I'm bound to have syntax errors that I'll pick up on.

The goal of the code is to set the serial port Baud rate to 115200 so it can talk to the radio, then change the radio to a baud rate of 9600, then change the serial port tob9600 and finish with at&w command.